# How to get values from API with dynamic dates? Dart/Flutter

Tags: json, flutter, api, date, dio

I have an issue with fetching data from API, my goal is to get separated data like only dates and only values of currency. Basically at some point in trying to solve this problem I've got dates as keys but couldn't get the values of currency. Now I'm getting only nulls.

1. The response is:

```
{
  "base": "EUR",
  "end_date": "2020-06-06",
  "rates": {
    "2020-06-01": {
      "USD": 1.112558
    },
    "2020-06-02": {
      "USD": 1.118756
    },
    "2020-06-03": {
      "USD": 1.123471
    },
    "2020-06-04": {
      "USD": 1.133657
    },
    "2020-06-05": {
      "USD": 1.129095
    },
    "2020-06-06": {
      "USD": 1.12915
    }
  },
  "start_date": "2020-06-01",
  "success": true,
  "timeseries": true
}
```

2. This is what I use to retrieve that data. But I don't know how to properly go through the random dates

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:currency_exchange/models/currency.dart';
import 'package:currency_exchange/models/rate_timeseries.dart';

class CurrencyTimeseries {
  CurrencyTimeseries({
    required this.base,
    required this.endDate,
    required this.rates,
    required this.startDate,
    required this.success,
    required this.timeseries,
  });

  Currency base;
  DateTime endDate;
  Rate rates;
  DateTime startDate;
  bool success;
  bool timeseries;

  factory CurrencyTimeseries.fromJson(
          Map<String, dynamic> json, Currency symbol) =>
      CurrencyTimeseries(
        base: Currency.values
            .firstWhere((element) => element.name == json['base']),
        endDate: DateTime.parse(json["end_date"]),
        rates: Rate.fromJson(json["rates"]),
        success: json["success"] == "true",
        startDate: DateTime.parse(json["start_date"]),
        timeseries: json["timeseries"],
      );
}
```

3. Here is class Rate used for this code above

```
import 'dart:convert';

class Rate {
  Rate({
    required this.eur,
  });

  double eur;

  factory Rate.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Rate(
        eur: json["EUR"],
      );
}
```

4. The last one is here, how I send req to API, and its working

```
Future<CurrencyTimeseries> fetchTimeseries(
    Currency base,
    DateTime endDate,
    DateTime startDate,
    Currency symbol,
  ) async {
    RequestOptions req = RequestOptions(
      path: '/timeseries',
      queryParameters: {
        'base': base.name,
        'end_date': DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd').format(endDate),
        'start_date': DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd').format(startDate),
        'symbols': symbol.name,
      },
      baseUrl: _apiUrl,
      headers: {'apikey': _apiKey},
      method: 'GET',
    );

    Response response = await _dio.fetch(req);
    print(response.data);
    return CurrencyTimeseries.fromJson(
      response.data,
      symbol,
    );
  }
```

Comment: convert it to map. then use forEach to get every value or key in rates. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/dart_programming/dart_programming_map_function_foreach.htm

Answer (score 0):

This is how to access rates:

```
final startDate = json["start_date"];
final endDate = json["end_date"];
final startDateUSD = json["rates"][startDate]["USD"];
...
final endDateUSD = json["rates"][endDate]["USD"];
```

Comment: Could you explain it? I cant still get access to these random dates.